# How to Use $ and | Logical operators together In R

Tags: r

```
=if(OR([a]="1",AND([b]<=50,[b]>0)),1,0) - Excel Formula
```

How Can i Write this as an R code:

below is the code which i tried

```
i = 1
for (i in 1: length(a))
{
  if((dataframe$a[i] == 1) || ((dataframe$b[i] <= 50) && (dataframe$b[i}> 0)))
  {dataframe$c[i] <- as.numeric(1);}
  else
  {dataframe$c[i] <- as.numeric(0);}
}
}
```

I get the following Errors:

Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
Error: unexpected 'else' in "  else
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Something like `dataframe$c <- ifelse(dataframe$a == 1 | (dataframe$b <= 50 & dataframe$b > 0), 1, 0)` probably. Or `transform(dataframe, c = ifelse(a == 1 | (b <= 50 & b > 0), 1, 0))`

Comment: You've got an `a` and a `dataframe` as variables that we don't have and might be crucial to understanding ths. Also note `as.numeric(1)` is identical to `1`.

Comment: Typo: curly bracket closing `[i}` in `(dataframe$b[i}> 0))` for starters.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
within(dat, c <- ((0 < b  & b <= 50 ) | a == 1) + 0 )
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
dat <- data.frame(a=sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE), 
       b= sample(-10:100, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks Worked Like a charm

Answer (score 0):

There was a "typo" in `dataframe$b[i}` and one extra `}`.

So, sample data from @akrun:

```
set.seed(25)
dat <- data.frame(a=sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE), 
       b= sample(-10:100, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

Code:

```
i = 1
for (i in 1: length(dat$a)){
  if((dat$a[i] == 1) || ((dat$b[i] <= 50) && (dat$b[i]> 0))){
    dat$c[i] <- as.numeric(1)
  } else {
    dat$c[i] <- as.numeric(0)
    }
}
```

Also works with single operator:

```
i = 1
for (i in 1: length(dat$a)){
  if((dat$a[i] == 1) | ((dat$b[i] <= 50) & (dat$b[i]> 0))){
    dat$c[i] <- as.numeric(1)
  } else {
    dat$c[i] <- as.numeric(0)
    }
}
```

See the diference between single and double operators [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-complete-guide-to-logical-operators-in-r-9eacb5fd9abd)